# c# Form.ShowDialog(); does not seem to initialize my variables on subsequent .ShowDialog(); calls

Tags: c#, forms, initialization, instance, dispose

I have an application that where form class DataEntryForm.Show.Dialog(); is executed every hour at 57 minutes past the hour.  The constructor for the form I am showing has some code to initialize some variables which are used to set the index for comboboxes in the form.  After launching the application, the first form that displays is perfect.  The user populates and clicks a button to record data and close the form.  The next hour the form shows again, but the variables have not updated, and I was expecting them to increment by an hour.  I have tried quite a few things: disposing, moving the variables to initialize out of the constructor into another method and calling that method from a Form_Shown event handler.  I think I am missing something simple... I am a newbie.  It seems like even though the form closes, the next show.dialog is the same instance of the original form.

```
 //Launching Data Entry Form Code
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // note the DataEntryTimer.Elapsed event raises the button2_click event in addition to the form button.
    {
        worker1 = textBox1.Text;
        worker2 = textBox2.Text;
        worker3 = textBox3.Text;
        worker4 = textBox4.Text;
        // keep this timer interval such that it triggers the next button event at 57 minutes past the hour.

        DataEntryTimer.Stop();
        if (57 - DateTime.Now.Minute == 0)
        { DataEntryTimer.Interval = 60 * 60 * 1000; }
        if (57 - DateTime.Now.Minute == -1)
        { DataEntryTimer.Interval = 59 * 60 * 1000; }
        if (57 - DateTime.Now.Minute == -2)
        { DataEntryTimer.Interval = (58) * 60 * 1000; }
        else if (57 - DateTime.Now.Minute > 0)
        { DataEntryTimer.Interval = (57 - DateTime.Now.Minute) * 60 * 1000; }
        DataEntryTimer.Start();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text) | string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Work Center and at least 1 worker first.\n\nIf your name is not in the check box list, \nyou can type it into the text field above the list.  The field labeled 'Worker 1' must contain a name to record data.", "Select Work Center & Worker(s) First!");
        }
        else
        {
            LaunchDataEntryForm();
        }

    }

public void LaunchDataEntryForm()
    {
        Form form = null;

        //search all opened forms for one with name "DataEntryForm"
        foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
            if (frm.Name == "DataEntryForm") //this requires Form2 to be named "DataEntryForm"
            {

                frm.Dispose();
                break;
            }


        DataEntryForm DataEntryForm = new DataEntryForm();
        DataEntryForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        DataEntryForm.ShowDialog();
```

This is code from Form2:

```
public DataEntryForm()          // initialize
{
InitializeComponent();

DataEntryFormInitialize();
}

public void DataEntryFormInitialize()
{


// production hr----------------------
if (clockHr >= 0 && clockHr < 8)
{ productionHr = clockHr + 1; }
else if (clockHr >= 8 && clockHr < 16)
{ productionHr = clockHr - 7; }
else
{ productionHr = clockHr - 15; }

label17.Text = Form1.globalWorkCenter;

comboBox1.Items.Add(new CrewItem("A", 1));
comboBox1.Items.Add(new CrewItem("B", 2));
comboBox1.Items.Add(new CrewItem("C", 3));

comboBox2.Items.Add(new ShiftItem("midnight", 1));
comboBox2.Items.Add(new ShiftItem("day", 2));
comboBox2.Items.Add(new ShiftItem("afternoon", 3));

// shift---------------------
if (clockHr >= 0 && clockHr < 8)
{ shift = "midnight"; }
else if (clockHr >= 8 && clockHr < 16)
{ shift = "day"; }
else
{ shift = "afternoon"; }

if (shift == "midnight")
{
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("12:00am - 1:00am, Hour 1", 0));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("1:00am - 2:00am, Hour 2", 1));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("2:00am - 3:00am, Hour 3", 2));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("3:00am - 4:00am, Hour 4", 3));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("4:00am - 5:00am, Hour 5", 4));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("5:00am - 6:00am, Hour 6", 5));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("6:00am - 7:00am, Hour 7", 6));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("7:00am - 8:00am, Hour 8", 7));
}

if (shift == "day")
{
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("8:00am - 9:00am, Hour 1", 8));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("9:00am - 10:00am, Hour 2", 9));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("10:00am - 11:00am, Hour 3", 10));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("11:00am - 12:00pm, Hour 4", 11));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("12:00pm - 1:00pm, Hour 5", 12));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("1:00pm - 2:00pm, Hour 6", 13));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("2:00pm - 3:00pm, Hour 7", 14));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("3:00pm - 4:00pm, Hour 8", 15));
}

if (shift == "afternoon")
{
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("4:00pm - 5:00pm, Hour 1", 16));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("5:00pm - 6:00pm, Hour 2", 17));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("6:00pm - 7:00pm, Hour 3", 18));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("7:00pm - 8:00pm, Hour 4", 19));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("8:00pm - 9:00pm, Hour 5", 20));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("9:00pm - 10:00pm, Hour 6", 21));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("10:00pm - 11:00pm, Hour 7", 22));
    comboBox3.Items.Add(new ProdHrItem("11:00pm - 12:00pm, Hour 8", 23));

}

// select the default production hour in ComboBox3.
Update_Hour();
}

//  ---- production hour default index setting
private void Update_Hour()
{
int indexoffset = 0;
if (clockHr == 0 | clockHr < 8)
{ indexoffset = 0; }
else if (clockHr >= 8 && clockHr < 16)
{ indexoffset = 8; }
else if (clockHr >= 16 && clockHr <= 23)
{ indexoffset = 16; }
comboBox3.SelectedIndex = clockHr - indexoffset;  //valid indeces are 0 to 7... so hour 0,8,16 = index 0



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      ///   ---------INITIATE RECORD DATA TO DATABASE-----------
{
    if (textBox2.Text == "0")
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("No cuts, or red time were recorded.\n\nAre you sure you want to record this data?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        { RecordRedGreenData(); }
    }
    else
    { RecordRedGreenData(); }
}


private void RecordRedGreenData()
{                
    int selectedIndex = comboBox3.SelectedIndex;        

    if (!recordOperatorData.IsBusy)
    { recordOperatorData.RunWorkerAsync(); }

}         
}

private void recordOperatorData_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
SqlUpdate_Red_Green_Records myRecordInsert = new SqlUpdate_Red_Green_Records();   // instantiate an sql insert updateobject
myRecordInsert.UpdateRedGreenNow();            // call the method in the class to initiate the connection and data record insert.  Pass the record set as the argument.

}

// close the form after the sql insert/update is complete
private void recordOperatorData_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,  unWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Cancelled == true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Operator hourly product record Background Task Canceled!");
}
else if (e.Error != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Operarator hourly product record Task Error: " + e.Error.Message);
}
Close();
}




public static DateTime productionDateTimeobj = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30);
public static string productionDateTime = productionDateTimeobj.ToString();
public static int yearMo = int.Parse(productionDateTimeobj.ToString("yyyyMM"));
public int clockHr = Convert.ToInt32(productionDateTimeobj.ToString("HH"));
public static int productionHr;
```

Comment: Where are things like `clockHr` defined? You need to provide a [mcve] for people to be able to help you.

Comment: clockHr is defined at the class level... maybe this is the problem...should it be in the constructor?  I added the code for clockHr declaration to the code block above.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new dialog form instance, so there it cannot be using the disposed form.

> DataEntryForm DataEntryForm = new DataEntryForm();
>
> **DataEntryForm.ShowDialog();**

Can you elaborate more about the following sentence?

> "but the variables have not updated, and I was expecting them to
> increment by an hour"

Maybe the problem is the logic and not the window. I strongly recommend to separate the logic to a dedicated method and test it regardless of the form. By doing that, you isolate the problem.
I hope it gave you a lead.

Comment: I am expecting clockHr to increment each hour when the form is shown, and productionHr to also be set appropriately between values 1 and 8.  But each hour, when the form is shown the values are not incrementing.  I was declaring and defining clockHr at the class level... I suspect I need to move the definition into the constructor?

Comment: Where do you initialize "clockHr" variable? This may be the problem

Comment: It is initialized at the class level:  public static DateTime productionDateTimeobj = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30);
public static string productionDateTime = productionDateTimeobj.ToString();
public static int yearMo = int.Parse(productionDateTimeobj.ToString("yyyyMM"));
public int clockHr = Convert.ToInt32(productionDateTimeobj.ToString("HH"));

Comment: So evedy time this variable is initialized when the form is created. If it's been initialize with the **same value** each time, then there won't be any difference. 
What's its initial value?

Comment: The initial value would correspond to the the hour parsed out as an integer from Datetime.Now value offset by 30 minutes.  The first instance is always correct.  So I am going to move this code into the constructor and I think this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  clockHr was declared and a value was defined at the class level.  The value should have been defined in the constructor.  Working perfect now.